# Is it not possible to pass address of a variable as argument to a recursive function that accepts integer pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, factorial

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int *num);

int main(void) {
    int num = 5;
    int result = fact(&num);

    printf("Factorial = %d", result);

    return 0;
}

int fact(int *num) {
    int factres;
    int numVal = *num;

    if (numVal == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    factres = *num * fact(&numVal - 1);
    return factres;
}
```

I am learning to use pointers and functions in C and wrote the above code to find the factorial of a number. As far as I can tell the code seems fine. I have declared the function with integer pointer arguments and defined it below main. I am passing the address of the variable in the function call for calculation of the factorial. Where am I going wrong? I get `Factorial = 0` as the output.

Comment: What do you think `&numVal - 1` expression does?

Comment: There's no good reason to use a pointer type as a parameter for `fact`.

Comment: Tip: The input should be unsigned, and `if (numVal == 1)` should be `if (numVal <= 1)` because 0! = 1

Answer (score 1):

You subtract from the `numVal` address, but not from its value. Use `&--numVal` instead of `&numVal - 1` when you call the function.